# Slight craclinkg with Ubuntu and Behringer usb mixer / soundcard

Tags: sound, soundcard

When I play music on my laptop I experience slight craclinkgs that tends to be very annoying when you notice them.

I use a Behringer Xenyx 302 USB. But I actually have noticed that it occurs with the laptop headphone jack.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I figured out that my mixer soundcard has a sample rate of 48000kHz. But in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, I have :

```
; default-sample-rate = 44100
```

(the ; means it's commented out)

So I set it to :

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

then I restarted it with :

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --check
pulseaudio --start
```

And it did the trick !